# Access javascript functions from website on internet

Tags: javascript

I want to access the javascript functions on a webpage on the internet like msn.com. 
Is that possible? How can I do it? Should I download the page to my end and use those functions?

Comment: View source, copy paste?

Comment: Check licenses first if you are copying someone else's script. Also make sure you can read the script and know everything it does.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tools out there that can help you to do these things.

Google Chrome's Dev tools can be accessed by right clicking anything and selecting inspect element. The documentation for Chrome dev tools can be found here: developers.Google.com/chrome-developer-tools

Firefox has a similar toolkit called Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the soure code of the page (`Ctrl+U` in Firefox) and look for `<script>` tags. The JavaScript code can be either embedded in the source code or linked using `<script src=...>` - in that case just clicking on the source url will show you the linked JavaScript file.

I also recommend using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or the integrated web developer tools in Firefox (`Firefox > Web Developer > ...`). Google has such features too.

Good luck with msn.com, though. JavaScript on such pages is usually minified so it won't be readable for you anyway. It's easier to learn how to do things yourself than trying to reverse engineer such things.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Hm, nice one, can come in handy some day...

Comment: I was thinking I needed to tap into the servers or something to run stuff on msn.com   I realized I needed to just copy down the code and run it on my end. FYI, the copyright is no problem, this is for msn.com ;)